# Can someone explain in depth how those two calls were different

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

This is what happen when i execute the following function,the AjaxCallFive is executed only after the AjaxCallFour gets executed.

```
var ajaxOptionsFour = {
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Home/AjaxCallFour',
    data: { value: '10' },
    success: updatePage,
    error: printError
};

var ajaxFive = function () {
    return {
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/AjaxCallFive',
        data: { value: '10', dumyContent:"" },
        success: updatePage,
        error: printError
    }
}

 var a1 = $.ajax(ajaxOptionsFour);
    var a2 = a1.then(
        function (data) {
            // .then() returns a new promise
            return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Home/AjaxCallFive',
                data: { value: '10', dumyContent:  data.data },
                success: function (response) { console.log(response.dumyContent) },
                error: function (response) { console.log() }
            });
        });

a2.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data.data + data.waitValue);
});
```

However if i change the a2 variable line as below the two function called simultaneously, AjaxCallFive gets executed without waiting for the AjaxCallFour to gets executed first.

```
var a2 = a1.then($.ajax(ajaxFive()));
```

Comment: because you are calling the Ajax call and what it returns is stored. In this case it is a promise that is being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to pass a handler function to `.then()`. You're passing the Promise returned from `$.ajax()` in the code

```
var a2 = a1.then($.ajax(ajaxFive()));
```

The return value from that `$.ajax()` call is not what `.then()` expects.

It should be

```
var a2 = a1.then(function(data) {
  return $.ajax(ajaxFive());
});
```

By passing in a function to `.then()`, your second ajax call won't begin until the Promise mechanism actually *calls* that function.

Additionally, you can enhance `ajaxFive()` so that you can pass in the returned data from the previous step:

```
var ajaxFive = function (content) {
    return {
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/AjaxCallFive',
        data: { value: '10', dumyContent: content },
        success: updatePage,
        error: printError
    };
};
```

and then:

```
var a2 = a1.then(function(data) {
  return $.ajax(ajaxFive(data.data));
});
```